# How to take Oracle-xe-11g backup from running Docker container

Tags: docker, oracle11g, database-backups

I am running oracle-xe-11g on rancher os. I want to take the data backup of my DB. When I tried with the command

```
docker exec -it $Container_Name /bin/bash
```

then I entered:

```
exp userid=username/password file=test.dmp
```

It is working fine, and it created the `test.dump` file.

But I want to run the command with the `docker exec` command itself. When I tried this command:

```
docker exec $Container_Name sh -C exp userid=username/password file=test.dmp
```

I am getting this error message: `sh: 0: Can't open exp.`

Comment: if you replace sh by bash in your command?

Comment: I need your image name so I can run tests.

Comment: docker run -d --name Oracle-DB -p 49160:22 -p 1521:1521 -e ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true wnameless/oracle-xe-11g

This the command which I run for Oracle db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is: 
When running `bash` with `-c` switch  it is not running as interactive or a login shell so `bash` won't read the same startup scripts. Anything set in `/etc/profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, or `~/.profile` would be skipped.

Workaround:

run your container with following command:

```
sudo docker run -d --name Oracle-DB -p 49160:22 -p 1521:1521 -e ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true -e ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe -e PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin -e ORACLE_SID=XE -e SHLVL=1 wnameless/oracle-xe-11g
```

What I'm doing is specifying the environment variables set in the container using `docker`.

Now for generating the backup file:

```
sudo docker exec -it e0e6a0d3e6a9 /bin/bash -c "exp userid=system/oracle file=/test.dmp"
```

Please note the file will be created inside the container, so you need to copy it to docker host via `docker cp command`

Comment: tried with path to exp getting error
Message 206 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, fVerify that ORACLE_HOME is properly set

Export terminated unsuccessfully

EXP-00000: Message 0 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=EXP[rancher@ip-172-31-27-83 ~]$

then tried to set ORACLE_HOME also. but again error.
then I wrote script inside the container and its running successfully. and if I try same thing along with the command its not working
command is: docker exec -it $Container_Name bash -C "patth /to/script"
Same above error I am getting

Comment: No, the error is 
Message 206 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=EXP: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Thu Dec 1 10:40:55 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracl

Invalid format of Export utility name

Verify that ORACLE_HOME is properly set

Export terminated unsuccessfully

EXP-00000: Message 0 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=EXP[rancher@ip-172-31-27-83 ~

Comment: docker run -d --name Oracle-DB -p 49160:22 -p 1521:1521 -e ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true wnameless/oracle-xe-11g This the command which I run for Oracle db

Comment: The solution worked for me.
But again I have another problem. 
Already many data is there in my container. so if I re-run the docker container again, all my data will get lose. 
can you please suggest me one solution to re-run the container with out loosing the data inside it.

Comment: Thank you So Much Farhad... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it. Mount a volume to the container e.g. /share/backups/ then execute:

```
docker exec -it oracle /bin/bash -c "ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe ORACLE_SID=XE /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/exp userid=<username>/<password> owner=<owner> file=/share/backups/$(date +"%Y%m%d")_backup.dmp"
```